# Datetime to varchar conversion error

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I know tons of such questions are already here on SO, but my question is slightly different than questions that already exist.

Scenario: Database has ApptDt column of type DateTime, with values in format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss". I am from India and dates are passed in European Format, "dd-mm-yyyy". So every time I am getting this error:

> The Conversion of a Varchar Datatype to a datetime results in an out of range value

Sample Query 1:

```
  Declare @EffectiveDt as varchar(29)
  Set @EffectiveDt = '27/07/2013'
  print Convert(DateTime,@EffectiveDt,102) // throws above error
```

Sample Query 2:

```
Declare @EffectiveDt as varchar(29)
Set @EffectiveDt = '07/27/2013'    
print Convert(DateTime,@EffectiveDt,104) // throws above error too
```

Question:

1. The two formats are valid and conversions are allowed in T-Sql; why are such errors thrown?
2. Are there any generic functions or scenarios to hold such to-and-from conversions inside SQL?

Comment: `CONVERT` is supposed to be used to convert from `datetime` to various `char/varchar` formats. The second parameter of CONVERT must be of type datetime.

Comment: @cars10 AFAIK Convert() Converts an expression of one data type to another in SQL Server .

Comment: Please don't include instructions about voting or closing in your question. Everybody who can has earned the right to vote / close as they see fit.

Comment: Also as a side note dd-mm-yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy are not the same, and your datetime column doesn't have any "format" - the format you're talking about is how Management Studio displays the data to you, but it is NOT how it is stored internally.

Comment: @AmitRanjan Yes, of course, you are right, but the third (=style) parameter only comes into action when a conversion to a character type is requested.

Comment: @cars10 that's not strictly true, it can also be used when converting *from* a string, e.g. `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '27/07/2013', 103);` - which, on a US English system, won't work *without* the style parameter.

Comment: If you've read many of the questions/comments/answers, you should have seen plenty of times people pointing out that `datetime` columns don't *have* a format (as I now note that Aaron is pointing out here also)

Comment: Also, if at all possible, avoid having the date in a string in the first place - where are you receiving this string *from*?

Comment: @AmitRanjan OK, where is the big bowl of humble pie I can eat now! ;-) You are completely right, but then for, converting `07/27/2013` back into datetime you would have to use style `101` (US American notation).

Answer (score 2):

What you should be doing is *NOT* using regional formats like `d/m/y` or `m/d/y` in the first place. If you use an unambiguous string format like `yyyymmdd` then there will never be an issue and you don't have to find all kinds of crazy workarounds. Just format your dates in a clear and standard way in the first place.

Just because you're from India does not mean you have to use regional strings to represent dates. If you're letting people enter dates in free text (which is the only way I could explain you ended up with 07/27/2013, 27/07/2013 and 27-07-2013), stop doing that, or validate their input. If someone enters 05/06/2013, how are you going to know if they mean May 6th or June 5th? SQL Server can't tell either, and there is no magic way (like there is in Access) to force it to guess, and transpose the numbers if they aren't valid. That is actually pretty scary behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Change `102` to `104` (german format)

```
SELECT Convert(DateTime,@EffectiveDt,104)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5997/0)

Comment: thanks your solution worked. If I am right then Convert(DateTime,@EffectiveDt,104) requires @EffectiveDate in German format.. or This converts means you need to specify the type of format 102 or 103 or 104 and it will get converted to the SQL datetime time format. Convert cant be used to switch the formats... Am I ????

Comment: @AmitRanjan: There's no universial auto convert function. So you should store `DateTimes` as `DateTime` and you should convert them to `DateTime` before they are passed to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just `CAST` it instead of trying to `CONVERT` it in a very specific culture:

```
SELECT CAST(@EffectiveDt AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: `CAST` function is translated into `CONVERT`. More, for `CAST` isn't possible to define a style for conversion.